# how can you get the current local time on my device with the 12 hour format in React native?

Tags: android, react-native, datetime, mobile

I am have an idea on how I could get the time but its always in 24 hour format, how can I get it into being in a 12 hour format??

any suggestions??

Answer (score 1):

You can use any js date-time library you prefer. For example https://date-fns.org/v2.29.3/docs/format
Regarding getting the proper timezone, first, you need to get your device's timezone with

```
import DeviceInfo from 'react-native-device-info';

DeviceInfo.getTimezone();
```

and then use this timezone with date-time library https://date-fns.org/v2.29.3/docs/Time-Zones

Answer (score 0):

use [Moment](https://momentjs.com/) format to do that

```
moment().format("hh:mm a")
```